# What does a colon mean after a function in a struct

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    node* next; 
    node(int D, node *N)
    :  info(D),next(N)
    {  }
};
node* list;
```

In the above declaration of a linked list what does the following mean?

```
node(int D, node *N)
        :  info(D),next(N)
        {  }
```

Comment: This isn't [tag:c]. It's [tag:c++]. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Answer (score 1):

It is the `node` constructor using initializer list to initialize its member variables.